# array(struct) to array(map)—PySpark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `df` with the following schema,

```
 g_hut: string
 date: date
 arr_data:array
     element:struct
         Id:string
         Q_Id:string
         Q_Type:string
```

I want to convert the `arr_data` column from `Array(Struct)` to `Array(Map)`.

```
g_hut: string
 date: date
 arr_data:array
     element:map
         key:string
         value:string
```

Original `arr_data` column's  Row looks like this,

```
arr_data:
[
{'Id': '12a', 'Q_Id': 'uac', 'Q_Type': 'action'},
{'Id': '', 'Q_Id': '', ''},
{'Id': '76v', 'Q_Id': '', 'Q_Type': 'form'}
]
```

I tried the following,

```
df = df.withColumn("arr_data_map", f.array(f.create_map(
        f.lit("Id"), f.col("arr_data.Id"),
        f.lit("Q_Id"), f.col("arr_data.Q_Id"),
        f.lit("Q_Type"), f.col("arr_data.Q_Type")
    )))
```

I get the following result,

```
[
    {'Id': ['12a', '', '76v']},
    {'Q_Id': ['uac', '','']},
    {'Q_Type': ['action', '', 'form']}
]
```

This is not what I want. I want the original `arr_data` with  the `Map` schema as mentioned above. How can I achieve this?

Below to create a sample `df` (original) with schema that has array(struct),

```
data = [
    ('A', datetime.date(2022, 1, 1), [{'Id': '12a', 'Q_Id': 'uac', 'Q_Type': 'action'},
                         {'Id': '', 'Q_Id': '', 'Q_Type': ''},
                         {'Id': '76v', 'Q_Id': '', 'Q_Type': 'form'}]),
    ('B', datetime.date(2022, 1, 2), [{'Id': '34b', 'Q_Id': 'abc', 'Q_Type': 'action'},
                         {'Id': '56c', 'Q_Id': 'def', 'Q_Type': 'form'},
                         {'Id': '78d', 'Q_Id': 'ghi', 'Q_Type': 'action'}])
]

# Define the schema
schema = t.StructType([t.StructField("g_hut", t.StringType()),
                       t.StructField("date", t.DateType()),
                       t.StructField("arr_data", t.ArrayType(
                           t.StructType([
                               t.StructField("Id", t.StringType()),
                               t.StructField("Q_Id", t.StringType()),
                               t.StructField("Q_Type", t.StringType())]))
                                     )
                       ])

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a higher-order transformation function to transform each struct inside the array to the corresponding map representation:

```
out = df.withColumn(
    'arr_data',
    F.transform(
        'arr_data',
        lambda x: F.create_map(
            F.lit('Id'), x.Id,
            F.lit('Q_Id'), x.Q_Id,
            F.lit('Q_Type'), x.Q_Type
        )
    )
)
```

---

```
out.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|g_hut|date      |arr_data                                                                                                                          |
+-----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|A    |2022-01-01|[{Id -> 12a, Q_Id -> uac, Q_Type -> action}, {Id -> , Q_Id -> , Q_Type -> }, {Id -> 76v, Q_Id -> , Q_Type -> form}]               |
|B    |2022-01-02|[{Id -> 34b, Q_Id -> abc, Q_Type -> action}, {Id -> 56c, Q_Id -> def, Q_Type -> form}, {Id -> 78d, Q_Id -> ghi, Q_Type -> action}]|
+-----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The output is [almost, but not quite entirely, unlike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wAuDhoRmzg&t=8m2s) a [Markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired result, you can use the transform function along with the map function to convert the array of structs to an array of maps. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    ('A', '2022-01-01', [{'Id': '12a', 'Q_Id': 'uac', 'Q_Type': 'action'},
                         {'Id': '', 'Q_Id': '', 'Q_Type': ''},
                         {'Id': '76v', 'Q_Id': '', 'Q_Type': 'form'}]),
    ('B', '2022-01-02', [{'Id': '34b', 'Q_Id': 'abc', 'Q_Type': 'action'},
                         {'Id': '56c', 'Q_Id': 'def', 'Q_Type': 'form'},
                         {'Id': '78d', 'Q_Id': 'ghi', 'Q_Type': 'action'}])
]

# Define the schema
schema = ["g_hut", "date", "arr_data"]

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

# Define a function to convert struct to map
def struct_to_map(struct_column):
    return F.create_map(*[F.lit(c).alias("key"), F.col("arr_data." + c).alias("value") for c in struct_column])

# Apply the transformation
df_transformed = df.withColumn("arr_data_map", F.expr("transform(arr_data, x -> transform(x, y -> named_struct('key', y, 'value', x[y])))"))

# Show the result
df_transformed.select("g_hut", "date", "arr_data_map").show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused with your answer. Where do I use `struct_to_map` function to convert array of struct to array of map?

Comment: @i.n.n.m: It was probably mindlessly copy-pasted from a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) response, without ***any*** understanding of it. Or in other words, [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun).